# Bootstrap Glyphicons Firefox - Some working, some not

Tags: html, css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I have a problem using the Bootstrap 3.1.1 Glyphicons.

In Google Chrome, the Icons are working fine.

But in Firefox, some icons are displayed, some are not.

For example:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
```

Should display the "log-in" glyphicon.

In Chrome the Icon is displayed, in Firefox it is not.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
```

Should display the "folder-open" glyphicon.

In Chrome the Icon is displayed, in Firefox it is displayed, too

Google told me, that Firefox might have a problem with importing the font files from a different server, but I have them located on my web server. Since some Icons are displayed in Firefox and some not, I don't think the Problem is within file access troubles.

The funny thing is, then I visit the Bootstrap Components Website, EVERY glyphicon (even the ones, my Firefox won't display on my website) are displayed correctly by Firefox.

Since the glyphicons on the Bootstrap Components Website work fine in Firefox, I compared the MD5sums of the files used on the Bootstrap Components Website and the Files I received via the bower download of Bootstrap. The checksums are equal, so I think I don't have corrupted files.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

OS => OpenSuSe

But I found the problem:

After deleting the fonts from my server, they there somehow still displayed on the website.
Chrome Console and Firebug did not tell me where they come from, but a network sniffer showed me, that I somewhere include a CSS from a foreign server.

After a search over my project, I found this CSS import in a third party bootstrap add-on.

Deleted the line and now my local fonts are used, and all the icons are displayed correctly.

Sorry for bothering you, should have had the idea to check a network sniffer for possible includes called from third party extension earlier.

Comment: And your OS is ? download original glyphicon http://glyphicons.com/ the test on separate page and then test on your website

Comment: How did you find the third party add-on? Which network sniffer did you use? Please give more details if possible :) thanks

Comment: Well "sniffer" is kind of a hard word ... Fiddler4 showed me the requests

Comment: You can find Fiddler4 here: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler